# Issue with text not wrapping correctly at screen boundary

Tags: android, xml

I have a table in which the second column potentially has long lines of text, and I have set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` which is supposed to wrap the text according to my screen width. However, the text seems to be wrapping at the wrong place - there is some content off the right edge of the screen before it wraps around to the next line.

Also, I can't seem to scroll either right or downwards using finger swipes - I assumed that that was automatically implemented in any Android programme?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy SII, but the problem also persists when my programme is run on emulators.

Code snippet of my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="true" >

//Other rows

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView android:text="Faculty: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/organization"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making your `TableRow` width `match_parent` and the `TextView`. This way the width will not adjust and wrap off the screen but will be forced to a new line on the boundries and the hright will adjust due to leaving it in `wrap_content`. Also For the scrolling you can wrap the `TableLayout` inside of a `ScrollView` to get unidirectional scrolling, not both up/down and right/left as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, so tables don't automatically scroll?

Comment: Correct. You have to enable such features.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the scrolling issue. However the text is still wrapping wrongly even after changing TableRow width to match_parent

Comment: Change the `TextView` as well. I missed that one.

Comment: Changed TextView width as well, still no bueno :(

Comment: So they are both match_parent?

Comment: Try removing `adjustViewBounds`. That doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Try adding wrap content width/height on the first TextView.